# Current rating of a circuit

Tags: current, resistance, current-limiting, ohms-law

Need advice:

I have a circuit board that is BMS/PCM for a battery as a protection circuit board. The circuit has an IC and has one MOSFET, transistors, and diodes. I want to know how can I increase or decrease the overall current rating by changing components. What components have the main effect? I know the Ohms law. I know current has a direct relation to volt and resistance. The Mosfet datasheet shows a current of 5 amps.

So can I gain the current change by changing resistors and or I have to look for the IC and the MOSFET too?

How can I change the current ratings?

[image]

Comment: You need to understand the circuit. Not all BMS are created equal. Most people would just buy a unit suited to their needs.

Comment: Schematic and data sheet links please. That's both of them.

Comment: @Andyaka it is PCM90123B next version of PCM9101